# How to determine the side of an octahedron and a dodecahedron using an accelerometer?

Tags: math, arduino, accelerometer, physics, stm32

I have three figures: a cube, an octahedron, a dodecahedron.

Inside, each figure has an accelerometer.

The sides of the figures numbered between 1 and n.

**Task:** determine the current side of the cube, octahedron, dodecahedron.

For the cube, I derived the formula:

> side = round((Ax*1/988)+(Ay*2/988)+(Az*3/988));

Variable "side" will give values in interval -3 and 3 (without 0), which means the current side of cube between 1 and 6.

Now I need to do the same for the octahedron and the dodecahedron. Help, how can I do this? Do I need additional sensors or accelerometer is enough?

Comment: You need write some code. That is how!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, here we need not a code, we need a mathematical formula

Comment: This not an on topic question. That is the point we are not a coding service. Read how to ask a good question. Mathematics is not on topic either.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, I didn't say "do it for me". I am just ask help, direction to search etc. Fortunately, I already received an answer. And yet thanks for attention!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a formula like that is quite clever but it has some undesirable properties. Firstly, when moving from one side to another, it will move through some intermediate values as a result of the formula that are geometrically meaningless. For example, if you are on side -3 and rotate to side -1, it will necessarily move through -2. Secondly it may not be robust to noisy accelerometer data, for example a vector that is part way between sides -3 and -1, but closer to -1 may give -2, when it should give -1.

An alternative approach is to store an array of face normals for the figure, and then take the dot product of the accelerometer reading with each of them. The closest match (the one with the highest dot product) is the closest side.

e.g:

```cpp
float cube_sides[6][3] = {
    {-1, 0, 0},
    {0, -1, 0},
    {0, 0, -1},
    {1, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 1},
};

int closest_cube_side(float Ax, float Ay, float Az)
{
    float largest_dot = 0;
    int closest_side = -1; // will return -1 in case of a zero A vector
    for(int side = 0; side < 6; side++)
    {
        float dot = (cube_sides[side][0] * Ax) +
            (cube_sides[side][1] * Ay) +
            (cube_sides[side][2] * Az);
        if(dot > largest_dot)
        {
            largest_dot = dot;
            closest_side = side;
        }            
    }
    return closest_side;
}
```

You can extend this for an octahedron and dodecahedron just by using the surface normals for each. No additional sensors should be necessary.

Comment: hmm just realized your answer is the same as mine ... (I will delete mine as you were faster) but just need to add: In case measured gravity is too far from `9.81 [m/s^2]` the mesh is not stand still nor free falling but accelerating instead and  and you should ignore such reading (assuming you are doing this on Earth surface)

Comment: @samgak, thank you for answer. I know little about normals, but I will study. Little mistake, you write `return closest_side;` in for loop, it should be after for loop :) For cube it works excellently. Big thanks!

Comment: @Spektre I think you should undelete your answer as it contains information not in mine. It doesn't matter who is faster

Comment: @samgak I added it as comment that is enough  I think

Comment: Hi, @samgak, I study about normals. I found this picture: [link]https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/Vertex_normals.png[/link]. I need 12 vectors in centre?

Comment: @samgak, i found *.obj models, but there 20 normals.

Comment: The vertex normals of the icosahedron correspond to the surface normals of the dodecahedron and vice versa. So you can use the vertices from an icosahedron model as your dodecahedron surface normals http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/obj/icosahedron.obj Don't forget to normalize first (resize to set length equal to 1). You also need to make sure the model is aligned with your accelerometer position/orientation.

Comment: @samgak, I normalized vectors. If the accelerometer will placed paralelly to the one side of dodecahedron, is enough aligment? If accelerometer is not correctly placed, the function will return -1? I always get -1 :(

Comment: The function will only return -1 if the accelerometer readings are all 0. Can you verify that you are getting non-zero readings from the accelerometer? Also check that you are iterating to 12 and not 6.

Comment: @samgak, for loop iterating to 12. Yes, I am getting non-zero values

Comment: @samgak, sorry, I forget to fix  "return closest_side;". Its works :) Thank you again :)